# Getting diary-mail-entries to work with mu4e in a script

Tags: mu4e, script, diary

I'm trying to start using the Emacs diary to remind me of birthdays and such using emails, but I've configured mu4e as my mail client, so I wrote an Emacs script using `(diary-mail-entries)` that I want to execute using cron that should automatically send reminder mails using mu4e. If I execute `(diary-mail-entries)` manually while Emacs is running, it works if mu4e is already started up, but if it is not already running it starts up, updates the mail and does nothing further. Similarly, when the script arrives at `(diary-mail-entries)`, it creates the list of dates, then starts up mu4e, then mu4e updates its mail database and outputs the mails it found, but then it doesn't do anything further. I tried putting another instance of `(diary-mail-entries)` under the first, but the script stops at the first entry and never gets to the second. I thought about whether I could configure a timed kill command for the process, but I suspect that this would end the mu4e and the next instance would have to start it anew. I also tried using `(mu4e t)` so mu4e starts in the background, but it still gets stuck. So is there some way I can start mu4e, then have the process continue running in the background while the script moves on, or get `(diary-mail-entries)` to start mu4e and send a mail in one?